# JQuery Safari Animation Jumpy

Tags: jquery, safari, hover, jquery-animate

Got this nav concept working fine in Chrome and Firefox but its very jumpy in Safari. It seems to half animate first in Safari before then running properly. Any ideas?

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <a href="#"><li id="first"><span id="logo"></span><span class="navigation-text">Home</span></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="standard"><span class="gallery_icon"></span><span class="navigation-text">Gallery</span></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="standard"><span></span><span class="navigation-text">Gallery</span></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="standard"><span></span><span class="navigation-text">GalleryGallery123</span></li></a>
    <li id="last" class="standard"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // On hover:
    $('#navigation li').hoverIntent(function () {
        width = $(this).children('span:nth-child(2)').width();
        text = $(this).children('span:nth-child(2)');          

        var newwidth = (width + 15) // Original width + 15px padding        
        text.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({"width":"0px"}, 0).show(); // Make the width 0px and make the element visible
        text.animate({"width":+newwidth+"px"}, 300); // Animate the width to the new size

    },
    function () {
        text.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({"width":"0px"}, 150); // Animate the width to 0px and hide the element
        text.animate({"width":+width+"px","float":"left"}, 0);
        setTimeout(function() {
            text.hide();
        },100);
    });

});

</script>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7HWax/

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that Safari doesn't like animating to 0px. Changing the 0px to 1px sorted the animation flashing out :)